# Adding CSS rules to elements added with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm creating and adding li to a ul with JavaScript. Creating and adding the elements is working; however, the elements aren't taking on the CSS rules I declared in an external file.  When I display the elements server-side with PHP everything works fine, but the CSS rules don't apply when I use Js.  I don't want to use .style on each element as I have quite a few rules.

Suggestions?

EDIT: guys/gals, I'm really sorry.  I realized just now that I changed a single-use class into an ID which I hadn't changed in my CSS file.  Thx @jeff

Comment: I would inspect the generated HTML with Firebug to verify the exact same HTML is being generated with Javascript as with PHP.

Comment: @ScottSelby I'm using jQuery for other things, so I don't mind using it.

Comment: @paulruescher - Since it seems my comment answered your question, I made it into an actual answer.

Answer (score 2):

The method by which your HTML is generated is irrelevant. CSS is applied to all elements, whether they're generated dynamically or not. Therefore, the logical conclusion that can be reached is your generated HTML from the Javascript and the generated HTML from the PHP differ in some way.

To identify in which way the HTML differs, you can use browser extensions such as Firebug to inspect the HTML. Then you'll be able to correct whatever differences there may be.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on *how you're adding these elements you can do one of two things...

if you're writing them in with innerHTML you just add the class declaration as part of your string...

```
innerHTML = "<li class='myLIClass'>";
```

if you're adding them directly to the dom as an element you add the class like this:

```
myNewListItem.className = 'myLIClass';
```

or

```
myNewListItem.createAttribute('class','myLIClass')
```

Answer (score 0):

When the element is created just do

```
$('#newdiv').addClass('classname');
```